# problems with py2exe, shapely and fiona

Tags: python, shapely, fiona, py2exe

I have a short python script, called `test`:

```
import fiona
with fiona.open("C:\\Essai_compil", 'r') as l_Obs_shp: 
    for shp in l_Obs_shp:
        print shp['geometry']
```

I want to compile with `py2exe`or `PyInstaller`. OS: Windows7, Python 2.7 (32-bits), 
I've got erros. With `py2exe`, the 'log.txt' said :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
File "fiona\__init__.pyc", line 78, in <module>
File "fiona\collection.pyc", line 7, in <module>
File "fiona\ogrext.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "fiona\ogrext.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide.
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

With `PyInstaller`, log says:

```
File "ogrext.pyx", line 12 in init fiona.ogrext (src/fiona/ogrext.c:19107)
ImportError: cannot import name ogrinit
```

Problem are related to `fiona` module or some `ogr` stuff... I supposed this is not a 32/64 bits problem; all the modules I've used are 32-bits. More surely a DLL problem... Any ideas ?

Comment: What Operating System are you using? was this the location of the installers? http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona

Comment: Check out this possibly helpful discussion thread http://www.mail-archive.com/cython-dev@codespeak.net/msg02271.html and Google for others.

Comment: Some precisions about this error. SPECIFICATIONS: I work with the [OSGeo4W's](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/)Python (2.7.4), for 32 bits, because there's numerous geographic modules for Python.`Fiona` comes from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona). I've choose v. 32 bits, for Python 2.7. I've copy the `Fiona` folder to OSGeo4W folder. PROBLEM: I've try to compile (with `Py2exe`) a simple module to read a shapefile named **test.py** (with `Fiona`) and write shapes coordinates into a .csv named **myfile.csv** (with `csv`), here: # test.py module # import fiona import csv shp

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when packaging a `fiona` project with `py2exe`. I think `py2exe` simply cannot resolve all the `fiona` dependencies. But fortunately `fiona` is well behaved: just add it under `packages` into the `py2exe` script and it will probably also work for you:

```
opts = {
  'py2exe': {
    'packages':['fiona'],
    'bundle_files': 3
    }
  }

setup(
      console=[{"script" : "test.py"}],
      options=opts,
      zipfile=None
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

Thks geodata, I can compile my script (where I use `fiona`), with `py2exe` if I also put into `dist` folder these libraries:

- `geos.dll`
- `spatialindex_c.dll`
- `spatialindex.dll`